# Is there a way to generate publicly observable random numbers?

Tags: random, web

I have a website that gives users different outcomes depending on a virtual dice roll. I want them to trust that my random numbers are honest, so instead of me determining it in my own code (which to my skeptical users is a black box I can manipulate), I want to come up with some other mechanism.

One idea is to point to some credible website (e.g. governmental) that has a publicly observable random number that changes over time. Then I could say, "We will base your outcome on a number between 0 and 9, which will be the number at [url] in 10 seconds."

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is an interesting and original question. I hope it won't be closed.

Comment: Is the interval important? Do you need something that's changing every x seconds?

Comment: @Andi: Something on the order of 10 seconds, but not too picky.

Comment: What you'd probably require (and building on @AndiKrusch's comment) is something that published a random number and a serial number associated with that random number, and a guarantee that the serial numbers are monotonically increasing. That shifts you away from having to guarantee clock synchronization and/or dealing with something that actually updates relatively infrequently. (I.e. you could then say "We'll use random number #53874736 which hasn't been issued yet"

Comment: Ten seconds is difficult. The only feeds I know that update every ten seconds are webcam pictures. You could use something like http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/ (updates every minute)  and publish your algorithm so every user can check if he is interested.
EDIT: I just realized, the earthquakes feed will only update it's time if nothing happens.

Comment: Doesn't this just shift the responsibility to the other party? I.e. why would users want to trust the 3rd party site but not yours? I'm not sure how much is at stake here that makes you want to go to these lengths but even governmental websites can (and will) be hacked if there's enough pending on it.

Comment: @RexE I edited my answer below with an alternative approach that I think sufficiently safeguards against tampering, and make the results predictable and verifiable.

Comment: This is a shopping-list question, and those types of questions are inappropriate here. There's a [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explains why they're not proper.

Comment: @KenWhite I can see what you mean by "shopping list" given the way the question is worded. It could easily be worded differently, however, as "how can I generate a dice roll such that users can verify its randomness". This seems to be how people have interpreted it, but perhaps the OP needs to edit to clarify this.

Comment: @IMSoP: The question asks for a "site/service" that provides the numbers to base things on, which is specifically a request for links to such sites/services. As such, it's a shopping list question. If it were rephrased as you suggest, it would be more appropriate here (as long as it didn't ask for links to the source for the numbers).

Comment: I reworded the question.

Comment: Couldn't you just mix in your server's random results with, say, `Math.random` or `window.crypto.getRandomValues` in the client.  That way both your site and the user's browser each contributes to the end result.  Unless there's flaw in my reasoning, I figure if you hash two 'random' numbers, but one turns out to be compromised/insufficient, then the hash itself should be approximately as 'random' as the other uncompromised random number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with [this site](http://qrng.anu.edu.au/index.php) myself. It has a public anonymous URL for several kinds of numbers, and realtime pages to observe them:

#### Hex numbers

- Number: https://qrng.anu.edu.au/ran_hex.php
- Stream: https://qrng.anu.edu.au/RainHex.php

#### Binary numbers

- Number: https://qrng.anu.edu.au/ran_bin.php
- Stream: https://qrng.anu.edu.au/RainBin.php

It also includes references to the [scientific explanation of the source of randomness](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3597793), and practical demonstrations of it, even one [specifically for dice](http://qrng.anu.edu.au/Dice.php).

From your code you can just retrieve the number URL mentioned above.

### Alternative if verifiability is important

A completely alternative approach: when the deadline falls, retrieve the homepage of an outside controlled, high-traffic interactive site, such as the [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) of Stack Overflow. Store the page, take its MD5 or SHA1 hash, and derive your roll from that.

You can then:

- Show the page as it was at the snapshot time to verify it's working HTML
- Its HTML source full of timestamps to verify authenticity and time of retrieval to nearly the second
- Let people verify the hash for themselves based on that
- Guarantee randomness of the value because it is mathematically impossible to predict what you need to change on a site like SO to trigger a given new hash value

Any attempt to tamper with this system, such as Jeff reiterating an old page on purpose because he knows the MD5 hash it produces, is easily debunked by the real time nature of the site - it would be visible for everyone to see the questions aren't recent to the time of snapshot.

Comment: That's nice, but the problem is that you can't "back reference" the current number.

Comment: I'd suggest using http:// rather than https:// for those URLs, since they don't seem to have set their SSL certificate up properly (and the pages load just fine without).

Comment: @AndiKrusch the backreference isn't a requirement in the original question, it's the forward reference he cares about - "in 10 seconds I'm going to pull a number of this feed, which you can all F5 on as you will to see it's really random". A number that literally changes every split nanosecond cannot ever be logged or backreferenced, not a database fast enough for that, and that goes for all true random generators based on atmospheric noise or principles like this site uses.

Comment: @AndiKrusch added an alternative approach  :)

Comment: The principle behind the alternative approach is very clever :)